# GNUPLOT - Add a 2D curve in a 3D Contour plot

Tags: gnuplot

I already have a nice 3D plot, with only contour projection from a data file. And I want to add a simple function on it. How can I do this? 
here the code:

```
 set autoscale
 set terminal png
 set contour
 set output 'Corrugation_uwtp_HorizontalWind.png'
 set pm3d map    
 set samples 50; set isosamples 50
 unset key        
 set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
 set xlabel "Horizontal distance"
 set ylabel "Vertical height"
 splot "CORRUGATION_C_UWTP.dat" u 1:2:3
```

and I want to add following functin:

```
 h(x)=sin(x)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not possible directly, you have to make it in three steps, as 2D plot:

1st plot the contour to a table:

```
set contour; unset surface
set table $datatable
splot dataf
unset table
```

2nd plot the contours and your function

```
plot for [i=0:5] $datatable index i, f(x)
```

3rd plot the datafile as a coloured surface

```
replot dataf with image
```

If you use a gnuplot version prior to 5.0, you have to plot the table output to a temporary file instead of `$tablename`.